# How to store a java.lang.reflect.Method into a database through Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I've got a class which references a `java.lang.reflect.Method`, and I need to store that class and that reference.

Does anybody know how to do it?

It seems to me I can't do it straightforward, but I think I could decompose a `java.lang.reflect.Method` into class-name, method-name, class-name-parameters, and store those Strings. In that way, I could re-generate the `Method` object from them when loading it.

Does it make sense? In that case, any idea about how to do it?

Comment: You've got the right idea, just execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save a `Method` instance in a database.  It is not serializable.

The best you could do would be to create a pair of strings that represent the name and signature of the method, and the fully qualified name of the class that defines it.  If you store those in the database, you can reconstruct the `Method` (and `Class`) using reflection ... provided that the class is available on the classpath.

> Any idea about how to do it?

It should be fairly straight-forward use of the `Class` and `Method` APIs.  I suggest you read the respective javadocs, and try to code it yourself.  If you have problems, ask a follow-up Question, including the code that is giving you problems.

---

> And do you know how/where I should specify that de-composition and reconstruction strategies? I would like Hibernate to do it for me in order that I don´t pollute my bussiness model layer.

In your Java code.  This is not something that Hibernate / JPA will do for you automatically.  (For a start, the caveat about the class being present on the classpath actually means that the reverse conversion cannot be guaranteed to work ...)

---

Actually, your "requirement" for persisting `Method` objects (in some form or another) is a sign that your application design has gotten *way* too complicated ... IMO.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! That´s it. And do you know how/where I should specify that de-composition and reconstruction strategies? I would like Hibernate to do it for me in order that I don´t pollute my bussiness model layer.

Comment: I´m sorry for my last comment. I hadn´t read the complete answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I completely agree: this ussually means a bad design, but this is a testing application intended to be dynamically configured by final users. That´s why it´s reflection intensive. I never do this kind of things in base applications.